# how to integrate $\int x^2\sec^{2}{x} dx$?

Tags: integration

Can someone help me to solve this integral?
$$\int x^2\sec^{2}{x}dx$$
I have tried integration by parts, but I can´t solved this problem

Comment: Are you sure this has a solution in elementary functions ?

Comment: I got $$I = x^2 \tan x -2x\ln|\sec x| + \int 2 \ln|\sec x| dx  $$ by IBT and the last integral does not have a elementary solution.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. I don't know if this integral has a solution in elementar functions.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says $\int x^2 sec^2(x) dx = x (-i x + 2 \log(1 + e^{2 i x}) + x \tan(x)) - i Li_2(-e^{2 i x}) + C$ where $Li_2$ is a [polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm)

Comment: Wolfram, how did you find this result?

Comment: If you are not sure, then it is better to double check. If the $x^2$ is just an $x$ then it can be easily done by IBP as it then becomes a staple problem that can be found in many intro calc textbooks